# how to extract string between special character in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this string `E:\patient\services\ec`.

I need to extract the word between the 2nd and 3rd '\'. It will always be between them but the word might change.

my result should be services in this example.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Replace "E:\patient\services\ec" with `<E/><patient/><services/><ec/>` and select the third xml element.

```
DECLARE @test varchar(max) = 'E:\patient\services\ec'

SELECT CAST('<'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@test,':',''),'\','/><')+'/>' as xml).value('local-name(/*[3])','varchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
        int secondInstance = myString.IndexOf('\', myString.IndexOf('\') + 1);
        int thirdInstance = myString.IndexOf('\', myString.IndexOf('\', myString.IndexOf('\') + 1) + 1);
```

That will get you the second instance of \ (backslash)

That should be enough for you to get what you need.

Woops, just realized this is for TSQL...

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @a varchar (100)
set @a = 'E:\patient\services\ec'
declare @b int,
        @c int,
        @len int

set @len = len (@a)
set @a=REVERSE ( @a )
select @b=CHARINDEX ( '\' ,@a, 0 )
set @a= SUBSTRING ( @a ,@b+1 , @len )

set @a = reverse (@a)
while CHARINDEX ( '\' ,@a, 0 ) > 0
begin
set @a= SUBSTRING ( @a ,@b+1 , @len )
select @b=CHARINDEX ( '\' ,@a, 0 )
set @a= SUBSTRING ( @a ,@b+1 , @len )
end


print @a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... may it will works for you...

```
DECLARE @exp AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @exp = 'E:\patient\services\ec'
DECLARE @chr AS NVARCHAR(1)
SET @chr = '\'
DECLARE @sub AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @sub = REPLACE(@exp,
                   RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@exp, 1,
                                   CHARINDEX(@chr, @exp,
                                             CHARINDEX(@chr, @exp) + 2))), '')
-- My Query

SELECT  RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@exp,
                        CHARINDEX(@chr, @exp, CHARINDEX(@chr, @exp) + 2) + 1,
                        LEN(SUBSTRING(@sub, 1, CHARINDEX(@chr, @sub))) - 1))
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a column name instead. But I'm getting error invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function.

Comment: oops I  changed the @exp = select column  from table. I aslo changed the nvarchar to 100

Comment: @user3115719 Is there any issue?